# Sync Chrome Mobile with Desktop Firefox?

Tags: sync, firefox-for-android, chrome-for-android

On my desktop computers, I use Firefox with the Firefox Sync service but on my mobile Android device I prefer using Chrome Mobile. Is there any way to sync Chrome Mobile with Firefox Sync? (I thought of syncing at least history, bookmarks and password).

**Comment**:
For now, I'll use XMarks and LastPass to synchronize my bookmarks/history (and passwords for Chrome Desktop only). But that's indeed not the ideal solution because I need a running Chrome to have the synchronization with my Chrome Mobile running. Because of this, I plan to write a small tool, that hooks into the web APIs of Firefox Sync and Chrome Sync to sync them against each other.

Comment: Did you ever write your small sync tool? I'm in the same boat as you, so I'd like to use it.

Comment: No, it turned out there was too little information on the APIs :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no direct relation between the Chrome Mobile and any Firefox version.

What you can do, is to synchronize the information from your Chrome mobile to the Chrome desktop version, and then, using a desktop application, pass the bookmarks for any other browser.

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is a FREE Bookmark Sync application that supports among others, synchronization between Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox:

> Install Xmarks on each computer you use, and it seamlessly integrates with your web browser and keeps your bookmarks safely backed up and in sync.
>
> Xmarks will sync across browsers too. Today we support Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari (Mac OS).

---

Additionally, you can go Premium and benefit from the Android application to ease the process:

[Premium Features Overview](https://buy.xmarks.com/premium.php)

> Xmarks on Android
>   The Xmarks mobile app for Android is available in the Google Play Store. You can also install via [lastpass.com/xmarks.apk](https://lastpass.com/xmarks.apk)
>
> It lets Xmarks Premium users access all their desktop bookmarks and open tabs on their device.
>
> Supports Google Android 1.5+

[Xmarks for Premium Customers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xmarks.android) by LastPass available from Google Play Store.

[image: Xmarks Options Screenshot]

> Bookmark Sync and Web Discovery
>
> Application that will allow you to carry your Xmarks (formerly Foxmarks) data around with you.
>
> - Sync bookmarks with Android Browser
> - Add, update, and delete Bookmarks
> - View Open Remote Tabs

---

As for the remaining browser capabilities, like saved passwords, AFAIK you can only pass them to the Google Chrome desktop version.

Comment: Does this add the bookmarks to chrome or are they only accessible via the XMarks app?

Comment: It will add them right into Chrome.